# AWS cli - setup multiple connections in one shell script to connect to RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I would like to streamline our database connection.

We currently connect locally through an ec2 jumpbox, forward the connection on the jumpbox to the rds db, and then start a port forward to local

- currently we have to use 2 terminals, ideally want to use just 1

```
# Login to AWS using SSO
aws sso login

# Connect to the jumpbox shell and forward connection with `socat`
aws ssm start-session --target i-0194fgavc352351cv

sudo socat -d -d TCP4-LISTEN:0,fork TCP4:my-rds-env.z01241nng2.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:12345
# record port that socat outputs: ...listening 0.0.0.0:53859


# new terminal - set "portNumber" to whatever socat outputs
aws ssm start-session --target i-0194fgavc352351cv \
  --document-name AWS-StartPortForwardingSession \
  --parameters '{"portNumber":["53859"],"localPortNumber":["44444"]}'

# connect locally to db with localPortNumber
```

- Can we use the `nohup` command to try to run this all in one terminal?
- Is there a way to ensure background processes are properly killed - IE.. if one part terminates, so should the others so there aren’t zombie processes

Comment: Have you tried `tmux`?

Comment: You don't need socat to forward a port to a remote host, something like this should work: `aws ssm start-session --target i-0194fgavc352351cv --document-name AWS-StartPortForwardingSessionToRemoteHost --parameters '{"host":["my-rds-env.z01241nng2.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com"],"portNumber":["12345"], "localPortNumber":["56789"]}'`

Comment: That worked! thanks. Is there a way to check if the user is logged in so we can conditionally do an `aws sso login` ?

Answer (score 0):

As @Anon Cowards posted above, this worked using 1 command via `AWS-StartPortForwardingSessionToRemoteHost`:

```
aws ssm start-session \
  --target i-0194fgavc352351cv \
  --document-name AWS-StartPortForwardingSessionToRemoteHost \
  --parameters '{"host":["my-rds-env.<number>.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com"],"portNumber":["12345"], "localPortNumber":["56789"]}'
```